# Storing format for an image with its legend

Tags: image, storage, legend, file-format

I am trying to **store images of plants and their legends (as text) together**. However I can't find a straightforward way to do this.

I can of course use an "advanced" text editor (by advanced, I mean with formatting, not just raw text) in which I would import the image and write the text, before exporting in **PDF**. I have also thought about **html**, which could be used to create one stand-alone local web page for each pair image-legend. But still, there would be 2 files per pair : one for the image and one for the html code.

However those are quite heavy procedures and I would be much more satisfied if I could "simply" use a rawer format in which **the image's data and the text are sort of concatenated**, or so...

Do you know of any format of this kind ? If not I'd better just code it myself...
Thank you in advance !

Comment: You could embed the legends in the comment field of JPEG or PNG files and extract them like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32683651/2836621

Answer (score 1):

- Images can be polyglots of image plus text (not advisable)
- Images can hold text as steganography (also unadvisable)
- Images can hold textual metadata think Exif, Jpg comments, Tiff tags or  IPTC

You could even add a legend strip into base of image, but that's not "text". At time of placement you paste both image and text.

[image]

- HTML can hold image as text.base64 but the textual image requires 133% storage
- FB2 is similar in that it is xml with encoded images but the advantage of being stored as zipped FB2Z *thus nearest your concatenated requirement*
- PDF can hold both natively and if done right with less overhead than html but a bit more than exif.img

If done well as PDF/A both the image and text can be perfectly extracted raw from a PDF so image could be discarded, however, it is all too often that they are mashed beyond pure extraction or even reuse.

But in my case I can extract the image at 100% scale so its returned from this mini PDF here is the text

```
Hello, Flowers!
Microsoft Windows Welcome Scan
```

[image]

This was the code to store both together using cross platform [Artifex Mutool](https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-create.html)

`mutool create -o "output.pdf" -O ascii "Page1.txt" ["page2.txt" ...]`

```
%%MediaBox 0 0 595 842
%%Font Helv Helvetica Latin
%%Image Flowers1 C:/Users/name/Documents/WelcomeScan.jpg

% Draw an image. x width, H line elevation (y skew), x skew, y height, left offset, bottom offset, units are pt.'s cm is not centimetres
q 512 0.0 0.0 384 41.5 400 cm /Flowers1 Do Q

% Draw a rectangle. move line fill
q 1 0.5 1 rg 41.5 370 m 553.5 370 l 553.5 270 l 41.5 270 l f Q

% Show some text.
q 0 0 1 rg
BT /Helv 24 Tf 210 330 Td (Hello, Flowers!) Tj ET
BT /Helv 24 Tf 100 290 Td (Microsoft Windows Welcome Scan) Tj ET
Q
```

Notes

- %%MediaBox is Paper Size in points thus above = A4 Portrait
- %%Font needs to be added for text Style (Language) to use later
- %%Image needs internal name(s) and full path for pre-load Note this image is 1024x768 when extracted @ 100% but will be displayed by choice at 50% (512x384)
- Lines starting with single % are comments to remind me of pseudo PS directives to layout content. The blocks `q ... Q` are the guts of the page and are heavily abbreviated (after the value) thus `1 0.5 1 rg` is 50% green in RGB ! Remove them in a working template or else they may be added to the PDF :-)
- The trick is knowing how a PDF works page wise and places vectors or scaled images or text from bottom left origin bounded by a media box. Mutool takes the script and adds all the necessary overhead data for a valid PDF.

All the above can be easily templated and run with CMD or BASH, much in the same way an ePub can be templated then call TAR to convert folder into folder.epub, but the more complex ePub structure is not so easy to write in a script, thus suggest using a scriptable lib.

- **ePub is the goto answer** since xhtml and image are zipped in their native formats, and can be easily printed to PDF or converted to normal HTML + images

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm interested in your script for generating pdf but I can't figure out how to have it run on linux, especially because of the commented lines. Why are the first lines all commented and several with "%%" ?